# What is the thrust specific fuel consumption of a JT9D engine used for the Boeing 747SP?

Tags: boeing-747, fuel-consumption

I searched every inch of the internet still couldn't find the value of JT9D thrust specific fuel consumption (TSFC) , I just found the SFC which is around 0.37.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hi saad, welcome to aviation.stackexchange. I am made a few modifications to your question, I hope you don't mind. You can always edit your question to improve it further.

Comment: You could help the community in answering your question by adding a bit of information: for what phase of flight are you looking for the TSFC? Where did you find the SFC ( a link would help) and what units is the SFC in?

Comment: The answer is not available online. You probably have to look for it in the McGraw-Hill Aviation Almanac or one of Jane's books, which are not available on the web. The reason why its hard to find is that there is not one number for that question. It varies on the basis of many different factors.

Comment: I somewhat doubt the “SFC” you have is really power-specific rather than thrust-specific, because as far as I can tell nobody ever quotes power for turbojets and turbofans. But you really need at least two values, because for a turbofan the TSFC at cruise speed is usually around twice as much as the static one (but (P)SFC wouldn't be any better, the performance characteristics is such that both change significantly with speed).